# combine multiple conditions [AND]

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Basically I want to join two conditions in my htaccess file.
 1. either it should not be from multiple mentioned user agents and
 2. it should not be from particular domain

So , suppose my user agent array is ![facebookexternalhit/ , Alexa\ Verification\ Agent ,^Pinterest/]
and domain is xyz.com
then rewrite to abc.com

I have tried this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "!(Alexa\ Verification\ Agent | bitlybot/ | Blackboard\ 
                               Safeassign | ^CCBot/ | ^Clickagy\ Intelligence\ Bot | 
                               CloudFlare | Disqus/ | ^dproxy/ | ^EasyBib\ AutoCite | 
                               facebookexternalhit/  | ^Twitterbot/ | ^WhatsApp/)" [AND]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (w*)xyz.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ abc.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"(Alexa Verification Agent|bitlybot|Blackboard Safeassign|^CCBot|^Clickagy Intelligence Bot|CloudFlare|Disqus|^dproxy|^EasyBib AutoCite|facebookexternalhit|^Twitterbot|^WhatsApp)" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?xyz\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: hi just need to confirm will both the conditions here will work as AND here
i.e. to rewrite only when it is none from user agent and the host is xyz.com

Comment: Yes `[AND]` is the default behavior so both conditioned will be ANDed together.

Comment: above condition gets satisfied if my user agent is Whatsapp and my domain is xyz.com
and therefore it is redirecting me to example.com

Comment: What is exact user agent string you get from `Whatsapp`? This condition negates any user-agent starting with `WhatsApp`. So may remove `^` before `WhatsApp`?